# phraseapp how to set the locale using rails 4

Tags: rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have integrated the phraseapp(https://phraseapp.com) to my project, I am currently having a popup which opens when a website is opened,shows radio buttons for each language. When the user clicks on any radio button, I want to translate the project to the user selected language and the popup content too.

I am currently using rails-4.0.8, gem 'phrase'

Here is the code what I am trying to acheive, can any one please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("input[name=language]:radio").change(function () {
   /* here I want to set the phraseapp locale to the user selected language in the popup
      and translate the whole website */

});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to store the locale files with your Rails app.

1. Run `phrase pull` under your Rails app folder to get the locale files.
2. Set the `config.i18n.load_path` in *application.rb*, for example: `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('phrase', 'locales', '*.{yml}').to_s]` (change yml to the format you're using).
3. Disable PhraseApp (so that it uses the pulled local locale files) in *phrase.rb* : `config.enabled = false`.
4. Depends on your i18n configuration (see [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), implement the logic in your JavaScript function (maybe redirecting to a new url with a locale paramater).